# I only release objects if I create them using alloc?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

According to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000043-SW1) if one doesn't create an object using alloc or new then it does not need to be released.

Is my understanding correct?  So something like this does *not* need to be released:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple`s [Memory Management Rules](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html):

> You take ownership of an object if you create it using a method whose name begins with “alloc” or “new” or contains “copy”

So: You are right.

Answer (score 1):

If a method name contains `new`, `alloc`, or `copy`, you must release it.

You do not need to release the `NSURLRequest` in your example, it is **autoreleased**.

Comment: `init` does not belong to the set. It is just usually used in conjunction with `alloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Correct. You would not release that object. The only time you would is if you had first retained it (i.e taken ownership of it).